# Django: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to write a function to display all items in cart, but it keeps showing this error `could not convert string to float: "` and i cannot tell where the problem is coming from? i have tried chaging the `float(...)` method to `int(...)`.   what the possible error?

```
def cart_view(request):
    cart_total_amount = 0
    if 'cart_data_obj' in request.session:
        for p_id, item in request.session['cart_data_obj'].items():
            print("Item PRice is ##################", item['price'])
            cart_total_amount += int(item['qty']) * float(item['price'])

        return render(request, "core/cart.html", {'cart_data':request.session['cart_data_obj'], 'totalcartitems': len(request.session['cart_data_obj']), 'cart_total_amount':cart_total_amount})
    else:
        return render(request, 'core/cart.html', {'cart_data':'','totalcartitems':0,'cart_total_amount':cart_total_amount})
```

traceback

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Item PRice is ################## 
Internal Server Error: /cart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Destiny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Destiny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Destiny\Desktop\E-commerce\ecomprj\core\views.py", line 230, in cart_view
    cart_total_amount += int(item['qty']) * float(item['price'])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
[28/Oct/2022 22:17:42] "GET /cart/ HTTP/1.1" 500 68398
```

Comment: have you tried printing `item['price']`? it seems it is not a valid string to convert to a float.

Comment: can you provide the full output? what is after the `"` in the error?

Comment: I just did, it shows nothing, could it be it's becuase nothing is there to be converted?

Comment: it seems like the value is the empty string `''`, so the error in this case is exactly the one you are gettting: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`

Comment: I added an answer. In essence, at some point those prices are being set to empty string `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting an empty string `''` when trying to convert `item['price']` into a `float`.

```py
>>> float('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Make sure that `item['price']` has a valid value before converting it to a `float`. From the error traceback you provided, it seems `request.session['cart_data_obj']` is not having the right information. At some point where you set `session['cart_data_obj']`, the value for key `"price"` is being set to the empty string `''`.

Comment: Your anser helped solve the problem, i was not passing in the product price but an empty string. Thanks

Comment: @DestinyFrank, it is a pleasure. I'm glad I could help you.